# Javascript - return value is not considered an integer

Tags: javascript, function, integer, return

I have a problem with the returning value of the **test** function.
This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").hide( test );

    function test() {
            return 5000;
    }
});
```

After a bit of research a found the parseInt() function. But it didn't work.

1. try with **parseInt()**:

   ```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("p").hide( test );

           function test() {
               return parseInt(5000, 10);
           }
       });
   ```
2. try with **parseInt()**:

   ```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           $("p").hide( parseInt(test, 10) );

           function test() {
               return 5000;
           }
       });
   ```

I know I could just type:

```
$("p").hide( 5000 );
```

But that function will get more complex after resolving this problem.

Comment: What you pass into into `hide()` is the function `test`, not the result of `test()`. jQuery interprets this as a completion callback - "*call `test` after hiding the element*".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not executing the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p").hide( test() );  // note the additional ()

 function test() {
  return 5000;
 }
});
```

Comment: +1. But also tell him that without `()` was for assigning function (which will not work in this case) and with `()` it will execute.

Comment: :D I just can't believe I forgot those. Thank you very much.